# Access redux-form values through mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-form

How can I access the field values in a parent component of a `redux-form` component?

I'm not sure if it's caused by `typescript`, but before I started using `typescript`, I was able to access the form values through `mapStateToProps` just like how I have it currently. I've been trying to figure out what was different to my previous implementation but the only difference would be the versions of the `npm` dependencies and the addition of `typescript`.

**LoginPage.tsx**

```js
import LoginForm from 'components/Forms/LoginForm'
import Layout from 'components/Layout'
import { StatusCodes } from 'lib/enums/statusCodes'
import { storeAuthToken } from 'lib/helpers/auth'
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import Router from 'next/router'
import React from 'react'
import { connect, DispatchProp } from 'react-redux'
import { FormInstance } from 'redux-form'

interface IProps {
  login: FormInstance<IFormData, IFormProps>
}

interface IState {
  errorMessage?: string,
  processing: boolean
}

interface IRootState {
  form: IProps
}

export interface IFormData {
  username?: string,
  password?: string
}

export interface IFormProps {
  contactId?: string,
  errorMessage?: string,
  fieldValues: Partial<IFormData>,
  processing: boolean
}

class LoginPage extends React.Component<NextPage & DispatchProp & IProps, IState> {
  state = {
    errorMessage: undefined,
    processing: false
  }

  setErrorMessage = (message: string) => {
    this.setState({
      errorMessage: message,
      processing: false
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = async (values: IFormData) => {
    if (values && values.username && values.password) {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: undefined,
        processing: true
      })
  
      try {
        const { dispatch } = this.props
  
        await storeAuthToken(dispatch, values.username, values.password)
        Router.push('/')
      } catch (error) {
        if (error === StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST) {
          this.setErrorMessage("Sorry, you have entered incorrect details. Please try again.")
        } else {
          this.setErrorMessage("Sorry, there was an issue trying to log you in")
        }
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { login } = this.props
    const { processing } = this.state

    return (
      <Layout title="Login">
        <div className="form-wrapper full">
          <LoginForm processing={processing} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} fieldValues={login.values} />
        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ form: { login } }: IRootState) => ({ login })

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginPage)
```

**LoginForm.tsx**

```js
import Link from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'
import { Field, InjectedFormProps, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import FormButton from 'components/Forms/FormButton'
import Input from 'components/Fields/Input'
import { validateRequired } from 'lib/helpers/validators'
import { IFormProps, IFormData } from 'pages/login'

class LoginForm extends React.Component<IFormProps & InjectedFormProps<IFormData, IFormProps>> {
  render() {
    const { contactId, errorMessage, fieldValues, handleSubmit, processing } = this.props

    return (
      <form id="login" onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <h1>Sign in</h1>
        <fieldset>
          <div className="fields">
            {
              !contactId
                ? <Field name="username" type="text" component={Input} label="Username" validate={validateRequired} />
                : <Field name="username" type="email" component={Input} label="Email" validate={validateRequired} />
            } 
          </div>
          <div className="fields">
            <Field name="password" type="password" component={Input} label="Password" validate={validateRequired} />
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        { errorMessage && <p className="error-message">{errorMessage}</p> }
        <div className="form-bottom">
          <Link href="/"/*{`/forgot-password${fields.email ? `?email=${encodeURIComponent(fields.email)}` : ''}`}*/>
            <a className="inline">Forgotten your password?</a>
          </Link>
          <FormButton loading={processing}>
            Login
          </FormButton>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default reduxForm<{}, IFormProps>({ form: 'login' })(LoginForm)
```

**Here is my redux store file incase if that is coded incorrectly**

```js
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE, MakeStore } from 'next-redux-wrapper'
import { AnyAction, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore, Reducer } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
import thunkMiddleware, { ThunkMiddleware } from 'redux-thunk'
import authReducer, { AuthState } from './auth/reducer'
import contactReducer, { ContactState } from './contact/reducer'
import initialState from './initialState'

export interface State {
  auth: AuthState
  contact: ContactState
}

const bindMiddleware = (middleware: [ThunkMiddleware]) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension')
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
  }

  return applyMiddleware(...middleware)
}

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  contact: contactReducer,
  form: formReducer
})

const reducer: Reducer = (state: State, action: AnyAction) => {
  if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
    const nextState: Reducer = {
      ...state,
      ...action.payload
    }

    return nextState
  } else {
    return combinedReducer
  }
}

const makeStore: MakeStore<State> = () => createStore(reducer, initialState, bindMiddleware([thunkMiddleware]))

export const wrapper = createWrapper<State>(makeStore/*, { debug: true }*/)
```

Comment: Is there an error? What are you expecting to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: @cbr The error says `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'login' of 'undefined' or 'null'.`

The way I wanted it to work was so that it returns the form state in redux so I can fetch the form values in "real-time" so whenever a new character is typed, the props will be updated with the new values.

Comment: In your reducer, `return combinedReducer` should probably be `return combinedReducer(state, action)`

Comment: @cbr It gives me this error `Argument of type 'State' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CombinedState<{ auth: AuthState; contact: ContactState; form: FormStateMap; }>'.` when I pass the two parameters to `return combinedReducer`.

Comment: Well, what does the rest of the error message say? I'm guessing it says that the `State` interface is missing the key and type for `form`.

Comment: @cbr Yes basically, `Property 'form' is missing in type 'State' but required in type '{ auth: AuthState; contact: ContactState; form: FormStateMap; }'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I missed out a key in the `IApplicationState` interface and as mentioned by @cbr, the parameters `state` and `action` needed to be passed to `combinedReducer` even though it doesn't directly take any.

Additionally it didn't like when the `nextState` constant had the type `Reducer`, so I have changed that to `CombinedState<State>` as well

The changed code looks like this

```js
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE, MakeStore } from 'next-redux-wrapper'
import { AnyAction, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore, Reducer } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
import thunkMiddleware, { ThunkMiddleware } from 'redux-thunk'
import authReducer, { AuthState } from './auth/reducer'
import contactReducer, { ContactState } from './contact/reducer'
import initialState from './initialState'

export interface State {
  auth: AuthState
  contact: ContactState,
  form: FormStateMap
}

const bindMiddleware = (middleware: [ThunkMiddleware]) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension')
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
  }

  return applyMiddleware(...middleware)
}

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  contact: contactReducer,
  form: formReducer
})

const reducer: Reducer = (state: State, action: AnyAction) => {
  if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
    const nextState: CombinedState<State> = {
      ...state,
      ...action.payload
    }

    return nextState
  } else {
    return combinedReducer(state, action)
  }
}

const makeStore: MakeStore<State> = () => createStore(reducer, initialState, bindMiddleware([thunkMiddleware]))

export const wrapper = createWrapper<State>(makeStore)
```